# Spot instance bidding strategy in Amazon EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My project is about determining an optimal bidding strategy for Amazon EC2 spot instances. I already have a document which is actually a research paper on this topic, it expresses the optimal bidding strategy via a recursive equation.

As of now my task is to implement this recursive algorithm, after that I have got to improve it to achieve more optimal bid price in order to minimize the average cost of computation while meeting the deadline at the same time.

```
B∗t = B∗t+1 − (1 − p)F(B∗t+1)[B∗t+1 − G(B∗t+1)],
where, t = 0, • • • , T − 3 and B∗T−2 = Sod.

here B*t (read as B star t) means bidding price at time instant t
     B*t+1(read as B star (t+1)th instant),similarly for B*T-2...

T is deadline of a job. Sod= on-demand instance price. F(.) & G(.) are distribution functions.
```

I am having problem in implementing this recursive equation. I am using core Java for my project.

I have written a code for that but not sure about the bodies of F() & G()
this is what I have done so far

```
import java.util.Date;

class Job{
    int computationTime;
    int deadline;
public Job(int c,int T){
    computationTime=c;
    deadline=T;
}
}

public class SpotVm {

    int c;
    int T;
    int Sod;   //On-demand VM price

    public SpotVm(Job j){
     c=j.computationTime;
     T=j.deadline;
    }

    public static int G(int t) {

    }

    public static int F(int t) {

    }   



    public  int bid(int t){
        if(t<=T-3)  
         return (bid(t+1)-(1-p)F(bid(t+1))[bid(t+1)-G(bid(t+1))]);
        else
         return Sod;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Job j1=new Job(20,75);
        SpotVm s1=new SpotVm(j1); 
        int bidvalue=s1.bid(10);
    }

}
```

Please suggest me possible modifications what could be done on this code.

Comment: @halfer,first of all I'd like to inform you that I personally didn't check this thread here for 3 or 4 months or so as I had solved my difficulties & successfully implemented the project on my own by 1st week of July.So I couldn't understand what made you conclude that I re added a request for urgency.I do understand such forums like this are run by volunteers who answer queries at the leisure,yet there has to be some reasonable response time.Otherwise people might end up wondering whether at all their queries are getting checked or not & loose hope,hope you understand my point.

Comment: Hi halfer,I think all that caused the issue was the sentence "any help is much appreciated & urgently needed,Thanks in advance".Well,let me tell you I saw lots of people writing this kind of statements at the end of their posts as conclusion whenever they post some queries or ask for suggestions at public forums e.g. Windows/Linux troubleshooting related help forums or others.So I did as I was too asking for some help,may be it was on java code instead of OS troubleshooting,certainly not to over prioritize my query.Anyway,I understood your point and from next time I'll take care of it,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

is more a java question than aws, ec2. but i guess you want something like:

```
public double B(int t) {
    if (t > (bigT - 2)) throw new Error("illegal value for t");
    if (t < 0) throw new Error("illegal value for t");
    if (t == (bigT - 2)) return Sod;
    try {
        return B(t + 1) - (1 - p) * F(B(t + 1)) * (B(t + 1) - G(t + 1));
    } catch (Error e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am not clear about how to implement the distribution functions F(.) & G(.),in the document it has been suggested to replace them with empirical data set.These distribution functions are over the spot price value..I checked in the Amazon EC2 site for a particular type of spot instance,only the spot prices at some particular instants have been given for a specific type of spot vm,not sure how to draw the function bodies for F() & G() from those data set.Thanks for your code suggestion though...